# Validate and display window alert

Tags: javascript

how do I validate to ensure a value for total or orderForm have been fill up if not it will display a window alert upon clicking on Submit button ?

It seems the below is not working at all .

Pure JS:

```
function va(){
                 var result = false;
                                var w = document.forms["orderForm"]["companyName"].value;
                                var x = document.forms["orderForm"]["forename"].value;
                                var y = document.forms["orderForm"]["surname"].value;
                                var z = document.forms["orderForm"]["total"].value;
                                if (x == null || x == "") && (y == null || y == "") && (w == null || w == ""){
                                     window.alert('Name must be Filled out');
                                        result = false;
                               // } else if (z = < 5){
                                  //      window.alert('Please Select A CD');
                                //        return false;
                                // }else {
                                 //       return true;
                                    }
                                    return result;
                        }
```

HTML:

```
        <section id="checkCost">
            <h3>Total cost</h3>
            Total <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
        </section>

        <section id="placeOrder">
            <h3>Place order</h3>
            Your details
                        Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType" onchange="change(this)">      
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>     
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="display:none">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            </div>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like that alert is only going to execute if all 3 values (w, x, and y) are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ((x == null || x == "") || (y == null || y == "") || (w == null || w == ""))
```

EDIT:

Sure thing, original line:

```
if (x == null || x == "") && (y == null || y == "") && (w == null || w == "")
```

I did two things. Switch out the && for || and wrap the if condition in an inclusive set of parenthesis (which probably isn't required but I do it for neatness). The original if statement reads as *"if condition and condition and condition"* meaning all conditions have to return true (i.e. be blank) in order to continue. I believe each of these values are required to validate the form. My proposed if statement would read *"if condition or condition or condition"* letting the alert box be displayed if any value is empty.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Thank you, it seems there's no window alert, am i missing something like event trigger or event listener ?

Comment: how about removing the 'window.'?

alert('message');

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (x == null || x == "") {
    window.alert('forename must be Filled out');
    result = false;
} else if (y == null || y == "") {
    window.alert('surname must be Filled out');
    result = false;
} else if (w == null || w == "") {
    window.alert('companyName must be Filled out');
    result = false;
}

return result;
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems there's no window alert, am i missing something like event trigger or event listener ?